# How to use metasploit java exploit with custom payload?

Tags: exploit, java, cve

I've been testing Java metasploit exploits on my VMs for some college assignment. I tested exploit/multi/browser/java_atomicreferencearray and it works great but with one of metasploits payloads from show payloads list.

I want to set my exe located on attackers machine to run when exploit executes, but can't seem to make it work. Can anyone guide me through this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to 
disable the payload handler
set payload to custom_exe 
and 
set custom::exe /custome.exe

This should get it done. You also have to keep in mind that the depending on what the exploit is doing, and how much memory space is is using, or rather how much memory space you have to execute shellcode, you may not be able to use a custom exe with this exploit.

let me know what happens.